# Trying to add Windows 7 to grub2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So I just got a SSD that I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on. I did this by using a disk. For some reason it would not allow me to install it from windows 7. So right now I have to go into my BIOS to switch between the two OS. I would like to add windows 7 to GRUB instead of messing with my windows boot loader. I have downloaded the bootinfoscript and run it and this is what I get:

```
Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 has 
                       1565300735 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 2639042559 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14536 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT

/dev/sda1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       206,847       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         206,848       468,991       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda3         468,992   234,440,703   233,971,712 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1              34       262,177       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sdb2         264,192 2,639,306,751 2,639,042,560 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdc: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *          2,048    29,106,175    29,104,128  83 Linux
/dev/sdc2          29,108,222    62,531,583    33,423,362   5 Extended
/dev/sdc5          29,108,224    62,531,583    33,423,360  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        EAB6-626E                              vfat       
/dev/sda3        4042B74842B74208                       ntfs       
/dev/sdb2        7C8C238F8C23434E                       ntfs       Main Drive
/dev/sdc1        dcb7aad1-97d3-4eeb-9e03-ea1f544733ab   ext4       
/dev/sdc5        f25dc0ba-dd80-4a39-8c60-56deb926b6b6   swap       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sdc1        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================
```

How do I go about adding it?

Comment: What is your motherboard? Is it UEFI? I have a similar issue on my UEFI motherboard which does not (easily) allow me to have simple dual boot option in grub.

Comment: My motherboard is the ASUS Maximus IV Extreme that is UEFI

Comment: Try this it has helped me in the past. It feels a bit like using an axe to cut cheese but....in a pinch https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @gunmastertex3, Did you end up solving this problem somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu, try running:

```bsh
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: or `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Tried Both of those but still nothing

Comment: Is your boot partition mounted when you issue this command?

Comment: What do you mean mounted? and It is not a partition but a whole other drive that has my Windows 7

Comment: It is probably mounted already. I meant mount in the linux sense. So, next thing I would try is the grub-install command. You should first  issue it in the correct drive, then do a grub-mkconfig. Search for it, there are several questions which covers it.